# How do I use olivere's elastic client.Update() service to change array fields, generic string fields and possibly nested struct fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, go

https://github.com/olivere/elastic
Version 5.x

The wiki documentation isn't really clear on how client.Update() works.  It's needed to completely change a field and to modify arrays. i.e. in the example in the wiki documentation, how would one go about appending and removing tags to a tweet or changing a tweet's content? Also if a tweet was represented in go as a struct and I added a nested struct called "echo" which contains a foo of type int, content of type string and another type string array, how would one go about changing any of these fields using client.Update() if it's even possible?

In my personal example I have this function:

```
func UpdateEntryContent(eclient *elastic.Client, entryID string, newContent []rune) error{
    ctx:=context.Background()

    exists, err := eclient.IndexExists(ENTRY_INDEX).Do(ctx)
    if err != nil {return err}
    if !exists {return errors.New("Index does not exist")}

    _, err = eclient.Update().Index(ENTRY_INDEX).Type(ENTRY_TYPE).Id(entryID).
        Script("ctx._source.Content = newCont").
        ScriptParams(map[string]interface{}{"newCont": newContent}).
        Do(ctx)

    if err != nil {return err}

    return nil
}
```

But I get this following error when I try to compile:

cannot use "ctx._source.Content = newCont" (type string) as type *elastic.Script in argument to eclient.Update().Index(ENTRY_INDEX).Type(ENTRY_TYPE).Id(entryID).Script

eclient.Update().Index(ENTRY_INDEX).Type(ENTRY_TYPE).Id(entryID).Script("ctx._source.Content = newCont").ScriptParams undefined (type *elastic.UpdateService has no field or method ScriptParams)

Comment: Include your code in your question for a better chance of an answer, this is too broad.

Comment: `cannot use "ctx._source.Content = newCont" (type string) as type *elastic.Script` pretty much sums it up. You can't pass `Script` a string. Try `.Script(elastic.NewScript("ctx._source.Content = newCont"))`.

Comment: @Gavin now I'm getting this:  `eclient.Update().Index(ENTRY_INDEX).Type(ENTRY_TYPE).Id(entryID).Script(elastic.NewScript("ctx._source.Content = newCont")).ScriptParams undefined (type *elastic.UpdateService has no field or method ScriptParams)`  I was following the website example as closely as possible (seen [here](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/Update)). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit where it's due Gavin's answer put me on the right track. This is for another `.Index` but the full function that acts as a generic single field update is as follows:

```
func UpdateUser(eclient *elastic.Client, userID string, field string, newContent interface{})error {
    //CHANGES A SINGLE FIELD OF ES USER DOCUMENT(requires an elastic client pointer,
    //  the user DocID, the feild you wish to modify as a string,
    //  and what you want to change that field to as any type necessary)
    //RETURN AN error IF SUCESSFUL error = nil

    ctx := context.Background()

    exists, err := eclient.IndexExists(USER_INDEX).Do(ctx)
    if err != nil {return err}
    if !exists {return errors.New("Index does not exist")}

    _, err = eclient.Update().
        Index(USER_INDEX).
        Type(USER_TYPE).
        Id(userID).
        Doc(map[string]interface{}{field: newContent}).
        Do(ctx)


    return nil
}
```

You can change the `.Index`, `.Type`, and `.Id` and it works with all fields and types as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

The `Script` method accepts a `*elastic.Script`, not a string. The `ScriptParams` method is also found on `*elastic.Script` as `Params` instead of being on `*elastic.UpdateService`.

```
func UpdateEntryContent(eclient *elastic.Client, entryID string, newContent []rune) error{
    ctx:=context.Background()

    exists, err := eclient.IndexExists(ENTRY_INDEX).Do(ctx)
    if err != nil {return err}
    if !exists {return errors.New("Index does not exist")}

    script := elastic.NewScript("ctx._source.Content = newCont").Params(map[string]interface{}{"newCont": newContent})

    _, err = eclient.Update().Index(ENTRY_INDEX).Type(ENTRY_TYPE).Id(entryID).
        Script(script).
        Do(ctx)

    if err != nil {return err}

    return nil
}
```

You can see more information about the package with [GoDoc](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5) or by looking through the source code.

Comment: I was still having an issue with `.ScriptParams(map[string]interface{}{"newCont": newContent})` but apparently just `.Params(map[string]interface{}{"newCont": newContent})` works. Also upon using this func with the aforementioned modification, I get this error: `elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): failed to execute script [type=illegal_argument_exception]` Any ideas?

Comment: You're passing in a slice of runes as a param. Try converting that to a string and using that as the param instead.

Comment: I tried the following: `stringified := string(newContent)` and used stringified in Params and I still get the same error

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to edit the stored array. For instance, if I were to update `ctx._source.Content[x]` where x is an int representing the location of the target element in the array, how would that look?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should resolve the issue

_, err = eclient.Update().Index(INDEX).
        Type(TYPE).
        Id(ID).
        Doc(map[string]interface{}{field: message}).
        Do(ctx)